# От чего может лагать редактор при пустом проекте?

Tags: unity3d

Недавно пояаилась проблема. Редактор дико лагает. Как будто я параллельно ему в pubg рублюсь на максималках. Даже новые пустые проекты. При клике по ГО в испекторе - отклик от 2 секунд до минуты.

Пробовал переустанавливать юнити. В том числе вычищая AppData.

Возможно, так на юнити сказываются так же недавно появившиеся, проблемы с интернетом.

Какие еще могут быть варианты?

Comment: Железо компа в порядке?

Comment: Можно удалить Юнити каким-то чистильщиком, чтобы реестр почистить, а то малоли..

Comment: Железо вроде в порядке. Во всяком случае ничего подобного больше нигде не наблюдаю. Только браузер из-за кривого интернета работает так, будто я через телефонную линию сижу.

Comment: Мне кажется, что дело в интернете. Что юнити постоянно пытается, что-то чекнуть и подвисает на ожиданиях.

Comment: Поставьте Юнити с официалки. Он не много инета тенят, либо совсем не тянет.

Comment: Добавьте информацию о версии Unity, также не плохо было бы получить скриншот диспетчера задач.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Последняя с официального сайта, не бета. В диспетчере:
диск, сеть, ЦП не загружаются более чем на 25%.

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц А если, происходят потери пакетов?

Comment: Вы меня конечно извините, но "последняя с сайта" - это не ответ. Приведите нормальное название вашей версии.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Unity 2018.2.9f1 (64-bit)

Comment: Проблема решилась. (неожиданно) чисткой кэша браузера. оО

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала посмотрите в диспетчере задач не ест ли у вас одновременно с Unity какой-нибудь тяжёлый процесс все мощности.

Второй вариант для проверки - открыть окно Window->Analysis->Profiler и нажать в нём кнопку Profile Editor, чтобы он подцепился к текущему редактору. В нём можно посмотреть что вызывает пиковые назагрузки, если выбрать окне "CPU Usage", нажать на любой пик и посмотреть в окно с информацией ниже.

Ну и если первых два решить проблему не помогли, то - да, дело в интернете. Если вы, например, включите VPN, при открытом Unity - приложение упадёт с критической ошибкой :) Это наталкивает на мысль, что редактор таки что-то тянет из сети и не умеет обрабатывать внезапные разрывы.